# How to serialize nested model in Django-Rest

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to use with the a legacy database. I have created models file using inscpectdb but now I am not able to perform joins on the table.

I have two tables job_info and  username_userid.

Here is my models.class file:

```
class UseridUsername(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'userid_username'

class LinuxJobTable(models.Model):
    job_db_inx = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    mod_time = models.IntegerField()
    account = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    exit_code = models.IntegerField()
    job_name = models.TextField()
    id_job = models.IntegerField()
    id_user = models.OneToOneField(UseridUsername , on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column="id_user")
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'linux_job_table'
```

Now how can I get all the values from LinuxJobTable and username from UseridUsername for the corresponding user.

Heren is my serializable class :

```
class UseridUsernameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UseridUsername
        fields = ('userid','username')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    username =  UseridUsernameSerializer(many=False)
    model = LinuxJobTable
    fields = ('account','mod_time','username')
```

When I try to access it, it gives ' Field name `username` is not valid for model `LinuxJobTable`.' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is raising because `UserSerializer` search for a relates fields named `username` and it doesn't find a one. In your case the ralated field is named as **`id_user`**, So you have to mention it via [`source`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) parameter.

So, Try this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = UseridUsernameSerializer(many=False, source='id_user')
    class Meta:
        model = LinuxJobTable
        fields = ('account', 'mod_time', 'username')
```

Comment: Added few info to the answer, though

Comment: `username = UseridUsernameSerializer(many=False, source='id_user')`  should not inside the `Meta` class